# std::getline() access violation, used to work but can't read from any file now

Tags: c++, file-io, getline

I have a C++ application which needs to read data from a .txt file. I have had this application working for about 8-9 months but after changing another part of the application, it errors out with an "access violation" on any call to getline().

Here is my code:

```
std::string line;
std::ifstream config;
config.open(fileName);

if(config.is_open()) {

    while(config.good())
    {
        std::getline(config, line);
        //Other code to do stuff with the string "line".
    }
```

I have no idea why this is happening now, could it be something to do with some std library dll somewhere or something?

I'm at a complete loss.

As a quick fix is there another easy way to read a file in line by line that would potentially by-pass this problem?

Thanks.

Oh, here is the error message:

> 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000014.

Comment: OS? Compiler? (Let me guess, Windows? Visual C++?)

Comment: What kind of other code is involved?l Because an access violation for address 0x14 means that you are probably dereferencing a `char`. Low memory like that is almost always OS memory, and is almost always addressed low enough that only dereferencing a char would do it. Do you access the C string in the `std::string`?

Comment: Try `std::getline` with a `std::stringstream` to confirm its `std::getline` and not a file permission problem.

Comment: I'm on Windows 7 64-bit and Visual Studio C++ 2010. A lot of other stuff is happening in the code with SFML, ffmpeg etc. but this bit is pretty much isolated at the start of the program because the settings are loaded from this txt at the beginning.

Comment: Oh I am on 64-bit and it's a 32-bit application so I don't know if that's a problem? It has always been a 32-bit application though and has always been developed across (3 different) 64-bit applications.

Comment: x86_64 is completely backwards compatible with x86_32 so that should not be the issue.

Comment: Ah! I've just created a new project and all it does is the code above pretty much: I open a file with ifstream and then do getline(), it works, but only if I compile it for x64. Compiling it for win32 gives me the following runtime error: "application unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)". If I use depends to find  the 32-bit one's dependencies, it is trying to find msvcr100D.dll and kernel32.dll and can't fint them...

Comment: anyone know how to sort this out? I'm still stuck on this, win32 doesn't seem to work on my 64bit :/

Answer (score 1):

This is not the answer to your question, but a general response.

Don't copy `fstream` code from cplusplus.com, your example should be:

```
std::string line;
std::ifstream config(fileName);

while (std::getline(config, line))
{
    //Other code to do stuff with the string "line".
}
```

Comment: Ah okay, is the cplusplus stuff unreliable/outdated?

Comment: Also, how does this fix the problem?

Comment: It doesn't, I said it's not an answer to the question. Feel free to downvote if you want, I care far more about encouraging good style (which I consider useful) than I care about my SO score.

Comment: cppreference backs-up @JonathanWakely: see [eof](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/eof) and [getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you replace all the debug .libs from linker and replace with them with release versions If you are using Visual C++ for The release Build.

ex: Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies (replace **msvcrtd.lib** (last char 'd' for debug lib) from **msvcrt.lib** (release) )